# What technology used to link Facebook and Messenger

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to create a pair of apps that would be linked as seamlessly as Facebook and Facebook Messenger.

(iPad) In Facebook, if you click the Messenger icon, it opens the app straight away. If the app is not installed, it opens a store popup for downloading Messenger.

I wanted to know if any of you had an idea of the technology they used to create that behaviour on both Android and iOS? Could it be [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)?

They might've used URL schemes on iOS but I don't know the equivalent on Android.

Any idea or thoughts?
If you've heard of something quite similar, I'd still be interested to know about it!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so simple ;)

You can open other application using its package name.

```
  String packageName = "com.example.application"   // the application package name you going to invoke.

  if (isAppInstalled(activity, packageName)){
     startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName));
  }else{
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that can be useful to me! Any idea if this is for sure what they used for Facebook and Messenger?

Comment: Very sure. This is a way to start one application from another application. It's just like opening your application from the launcher.